# border set like stack of cards

Tags: wpf, border

I am wondering what the best way is solve this problem I have a text block with an image around a border and I can add properties and I want to add a border around it to be like a stack of cards. I'll demonstrate what I mean with pictures. The first picture I have is what displays just now.

[image]

The second picture is what I want it to display if there is properties added in this example there would be 5 added properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  many borders that overlap, with a non transparent background.

The xaml  appearing order is the painting order.

So the last components appear over the first ones.

All the components are in a grid that allow many children.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <system:Double x:Key="width1" >100</system:Double>
        <system:Double x:Key="height1" >30</system:Double>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"             
            Background="White"
            Margin="120 80 0 0" 
            Width="{StaticResource width1}"
            Height="{StaticResource height1}" />

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray"             
            Background="White"
            Margin="110 90 0 0" 
            Width="{StaticResource width1}"
            Height="{StaticResource height1}" />

    <TextBlock Text="+6" 
               Padding="20 7 0 0"
               Margin="100 100 0 0"
               Background="Gray"
               Width="{StaticResource width1}"
               Height="{StaticResource height1}"/>

</Grid>
```

Note : the use of resources for setting same size to all components

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was considering using lines but then that would be a lot more code but wasn't sure what would have been more effective :)

Comment: Actually you're right, you may use lines or preferably Rectangles. But borders are cool. they allow to rounded corners ( BorderRadius property)

Comment: next step is to make a custom control that is a sub class of Grid. Add a dependency property for the count. And may be add some few dep. prorperty for the different appearances properties ( color of background, lines ...)